# How many bytes do we need to encode Arabic Presentation Forms and Arabic (range 0600–06FF)?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, utf-16

I'm a little confused about the storage needed for representing an arabic character.
Please let me know if I understood it right from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_Presentation

In  Arabic Presentation Forms-B( range FE70-FEff) encoding by utf-8 takes 3 bytes and by utf-16 takes 4 bytes.

in Arabic (range 0600–06FF, 255 characters) encoding by utf-8takes 2 bytes . how many bytes need in utf-16..?

What are the advantages of each encoding? When should we prefer one over another one to use it in steganography technique.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-16 takes exactly one code unit (2 bytes) for every codepoint in the range 0-65535 (0 to FFFF hex). Storage size is generally not a good criterion for choosing a UTF. Whatever size savings could be obtained by changing between UTF-8 and UTF-16 can almost always be exceeded just by using general-purpose data compression (e.g. gzip); this makes sense only when the total volume of data is large.

Choosing a UTF for the purpose of steganography is also dubious. Either way the "attacker" will be looking at your data as text, and deviations from expected content will be equally visible.